# Adding Q Lookup to Wagtail CMS Snippets

Tags: django, django-models, wagtail, wagtail-snippet

I am building out a restaurant website and using Wagtail CMS Snippets for the owner to manage menu items.  The list of menu items are getting rather long and I was wondering if there is any way to add a search input field to the Snippets admin window?  Below is an annotated screenshot for visual reference.  Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can easily be solved by using Wagtail's ModelAdmin module (http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.8.1/reference/contrib/modeladmin/), all you need is to add this piece of code to your wagtail_hooks.py file:

```
from wagtail.contrib.modeladmin.options import (
    ModelAdmin, modeladmin_register)
from .models import Product


class ProductAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    model = Product
    menu_label = 'Product'  # ditch this to use verbose_name_plural from model
    menu_icon = 'date'  # change as required
    menu_order = 200  # will put in 3rd place (000 being 1st, 100 2nd)
    add_to_settings_menu = False  # or True to add your model to the Settings sub-menu
    exclude_from_explorer = False # or True to exclude pages of this type from Wagtail's explorer view
    list_display = ('title', 'example_field2', 'example_field3', 'live')
    list_filter = ('live', 'example_field2', 'example_field3')
    search_fields = ('title',)

# Now you just need to register your customised ModelAdmin class with Wagtail
modeladmin_register(ProductAdmin)
```

It'll create a separate menu entry for your Products model that's customisable much like default Django Admin listing. Which means you can easily add different filters and sorters to a listing.

This is a very powerful feature and I myself don't show clients the "Snippets" section at all; it's just too simple and ugly. Instead, I create a separate ModelAdmin per snippet and this gives me the power of customisation.

Comment: Brilliant!! Just goes to show I need to dig further into the Wagtail docs!!

Answer (score 2):

The search bar will appear automatically once you set up your model to be indexed with the search system. You can do this by inheriting from the `wagtail.wagtailsearch.index.Indexed` class and defining a `search_fields` list on your model, as described here: http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.8.1/topics/search/indexing.html#wagtailsearch-indexing-models

(Note that if you're using Elasticsearch, you'll also need to run `./manage.py update_index` to add the items to the search index.)